# RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel in MAMP

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mamp

I need to set my `RewriteLogLevel` in MAMP to figure out some `mod_rewrite` problems.

I put the below lines in my `httpd.conf` and my local `.htaccess` file, but I am not finding a output log. How do I set this up correctly?

`RewriteLogLevel 9`

`RewriteLog "rewrite.log"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a full path like /var/log/httpd/rewrite.log.

Also make sure you have mod_rewrite turned on.

Comment: And if still having issues, remove the quotes from around the filepath. That was what worked for me.

Comment: And how do you find that path?

Answer (score 1):

Apache generally doesn't enable mod_rewrite by default, so you may need to add more entries to your httpd.conf file.

For instance, did you put in an entry for LoadModule that points to the mod_rewrite.so module?

Check this link for details:

http://michaelkrol.com/2005/11/21/enable-mod_rewrite-on-os-x-104-tiger/

Also, don't forget to restart Apache to test your changes.

Comment: Why don't you post your httpd file to show you have the other required entries in place too?  Also, does it matter that you're using quotes around your log file?